# Django How to add a logout successful message using the django.contrib.auth?

Tags: python, django

I am not using `all-auth`

I am using the standard authentication system and url's provided by `django.contrib.auth`.

I have also ensured that when logging out the user is automatically redirected to the login page

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "login"
```

I would like to add a message so the user knows they have been logged out like:

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'You have been logged out.')
```

Would I be able to achieve this without making my own view to logout.
Could I use `signals`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `user_logged_out` signal

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out
from django.contrib import messages

def show_message(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # whatever...
    messages.info(request, 'You have been logged out.')

user_logged_out.connect(show_message)
```

Comment: it is 2 days that I am trying to figure out the same thing for both login and logout. I am using django's standard built-in login and logout views. It seems this answer is what I need to implement, however, I cannot figure out where we should put `user_logged_out.connect(show_message)`? Principally it should be in login/logout views, but we are not going to modify them so what is the right way to do this?

Comment: create a signals.py file in your app and just copy paste above code it will work. no need to override views.

Comment: this may sound a stupid question, but the user that just logged in will see the message, right? I was wondering whether it could be seen by all of the logged users?!

Comment: I did implement it, the good news is it does not give me any errors, but the bad news is I don't get any message displayed too. I loop through the messages in my template so I don't know why it does not show the message!

Comment: i suggest you to create a new question for that, add some code there and elaborate your issue.