# Display messages on LogoutView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using the messages framework for basic things like success messages on user login. This is working fine.

I can't get it to work when a user logs out, however. I'm not a web-developer so not particularly strong with django so not sure what i'm doing wrong - there are similar issues:
[django message when logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393929/django-message-when-logout)
[Django How to add a logout successful message using the django.contrib.auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542502/django-how-to-add-a-logout-successful-message-using-the-django-contrib-auth)
with solutions in using signals - before trying that I'd like to understand why my code below isn't working. I'm clearly missing something!

Note in my template i've added a conditional to print some text if there are no messages - this text does print out so my messages.html is definitely being included.

**views.py**

```
class LogoutFormView(SuccessMessageMixin,LogoutView):
template_name = 'users/logout.html'
success_message = "Successfully logged out."

class login_view(SuccessMessageMixin,LoginView):
template_name = 'users/login.html'
success_message = "Successfully logged in."
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('recordings:projects')
```

**messages.html**

```
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**in the template both my login redirect and logout.html extends:**

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3 pl-5 pr-5">
    {% block messages %}
    {% if messages %}
    test-messages
    {% else %}
    test-no-messages
    {% endif %}
    {% include "common/messages.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: Does the message work when a user logs in? Have you made sure your project has all the prerequisites for enabling the message framework? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: yes works fine when users log in, and is working for some other purposes too e.g. updating records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LogoutView` is not a `FormView` so using the `SuccessMessageMixin` does not make sense here as it would not do anything

`LogoutView` calls the `logout` method and [the logout method calls request.session.flush()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush) which will delete any messages when using the [SessionStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage) backend

You could either move to using the [CookieStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage) backend, as I don't think this would be affected by `request.session.flush` or you could override the `dispatch` method of `LogoutView` and add the message after `request.session.flush` has been called although I'm not sure if this will work

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Successfully logged out.')
    return response
```